# using ToArray() on List<> of custom objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, join

This seems like something simple but I'm not able to get the syntax correct. I have a List<> of custom objects that have different properties (Name for example).  What I would like to do is make a string out of all the name in the form:

Name1||Name2||Name3

I want to just string.Join but need to get my List<> of object into an array of the names from the objects.

I know this isn't correct but somethign like

string.Join(myListofObjects["Name"].ToArray())

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `string.Join(myListofObjects.Select(o => o.Name).ToArray(), '||')`

Comment: AFAIK String.Join wants the separator first and as a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
string.Join("|", myListOfObjects.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Comment: note that this will only work with .Net 4.0. Previous versions of the .Net framework require an array of strings (so you have to call .ToArray()).

Comment: true - but I think only because of the string.Join overload - if you add a .ToArray() after .Select(...) it will work with 3.x too (LINQ) - if you need earlier versions you will have to to the .Select yourself (create array and foreach through your List) - just ask and I will add this code too